# Zend Framework upload zip to S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, zend-framework

I am uploading zip file contents to an S3 bucket which works fine but I also want to upload the zip file for the user to re-download later using S3 and Zend framework.

I can't seem to get the file stream to work though, no errors just empty content.  I also tried with the .html I uploaded successfully with the same zip and it was empty content when uploading as a stream, here's what I got:

```
$bucket = 'our/s3/media/bucket';
$s3 = new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3($amazonKey, $amazonSecret);
$s3->registerStreamWrapper("s3");

$file = $template_zip; // Uploaded zip file

mkdir("s3://" . $bucket);
file_put_contents("s3://" . $bucket. "/template.zip", $file);
echo file_get_contents("s3://" . $bucket . "/template.zip");
```

Comment: `file_put_contents` accepts the file contents as a second argument, not its name.

Comment: First is the name of the file and the second param "$file" is the uploaded Zip